# Помогите разобраться в 2 ID

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Если у меня в таблице `geo_state` есть два поля с ID - это `state_id` и `country_id`.

Какой нужен SQL-запрос, чтобы удалить из таблицы `geo_state` все записи у которых `country_id` (кроме **53**, например, и **54**), ведь и в `state_id` присутствуют эти номера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Добрый день!

Не важно, сколько и какие у вас ID. Главное, что это разные столбцы в таблице базы данных, со своими уникальными именами. При выполнении запроса:

```
DELETE FROM geo_state WHERE country_id NOT IN (53, 54)
```

Удалятся все записи кроме тех, которые в поле `country_id` содержат значения **53** и **54**. Значения остальных полей в данном случае никакой роли не играет.

Comment: спасибо буду проверять

Comment: все получилось удалил, вопрос закрыт!

Comment: @Pas, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.